# Store abstract classes in an array list

Tags: java, abstract-class

I would like to store the class object of several classes that extend an abstract class in an array list. Please be aware, that I have to use an abstract class and no interface, because the class Country will contain more functionality.

The idea is to later access this class objects, create an object of them and call a method.

Question: How can I achieve this, because the following code produces errors.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        // The idea is to add the class of all specific countries to the countries array
        ArrayList<Class<Country>> countryclasses = new ArrayList<Class<Country>>();

        // Doesn't work
        countryclasses.add(England.class);

        // Doesn't work
        Class<Country> englandclass = England.class; // Error
        countryclasses.add(englandclass);

        // Doesn't work
        England england = new England();
        Class<Country> country = england.getClass().getSuperclass().getClass();
        // Class<Country> country = england.getClass().getSuperclass().getClass();
        countryclasses.add(country);

        for(Class<Country> countryclass : countryclasses) {
            // Create an object from the class
            // Call the getName() method
        }
    }

    public abstract class Country {
        abstract String getName();
    }

    public class England extends Country {
        public String getName() {
            return "England";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to have a `List<Class>` instead of using a polymorphic collection of instances, you can use an [upper-bounded wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) to define classes that will be `Country` or extend it:

```
List<Class<? extends Country>> countryclasses = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Country>>();
Class<? extends Country> englandclass = England.class;
countryclasses.add(englandclass);
```

Comment: What do you mean with polymorphic collection? Just a collection of objects?

Comment: @dasskorpion a polymorphic collection is a collection of objects defined by their common ancestor. It's a powerful feature because, amongst other things, you can invoke the same methods on all elements of the collection, but have different behaviour executed according to the actual object type down the hierarchy chain.

Comment: In your case, a `List<Country>` would be a polymorphic collection of countries where you could invoke `getName` for each and get some different behaviour.